# Setting up recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, computation

I am given this question:

```
Algorithm Mystery1(A[0...n-1])
//Input: An array A[0...n-1] of n real numbers
if (n = 1) return A[0]
else temp = Mystery1(A[0...n-2])
  if temp <= A[n - 1] return temp
  else return A[n - 1]
```

(a) What does this algorithm compute?
(b) Set up and solve a recurrence relation for the number of times the algorithm’s basic operation
is executed.

For part (a) I know that this algorithm computes the smallest element in an array. For part (b), I believe that the basic operation is a comparison, since it will be done the most amount of times, but i can't figure out how to set up the recurrence relation.
 
I understand how to solve a recurrence relation, i just need help setting up the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence expression should be:

```
T[n] = T[n-1] + O(1)
```

Calculating the above expression the time complexity comes out to be O(n).

Comment: where is the O(1) coming from?

Comment: O(1) is for the comparison:

if temp <= A[n - 1] return temp
  else return A[n - 1]